# mysql 1452 while using insert into table

Tags: mysql, csv, reference, insert

i'm having 1452 errors while trying to insert data into my database.
Here's what i do:

```
create table Agenzia(
PartitaIva char(11) primary key,
Nome varchar(20) not null unique,
Pass varchar(20) not null,
Indirizzo varchar(35),
NumeroTelefonico varchar(10)
);

create table Parco(
Nome varchar(20) primary key,
Indirizzo varchar(35),
NumeroTelefonico varchar(11),
Cap decimal(5)
);

create table Affiliazione(
Agenzia char(11) not null,
Parco varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (Agenzia) references Agenzia(PartitaIva) on delete cascade on update cascade,
foreign key (Parco) references Parco(Nome) on delete cascade on update cascade,
primary key(Agenzia,Parco)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mypath\\Agenzia.csv'
    INTO TABLE Agenzia
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ();

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mypath\\Parco.csv'
    INTO TABLE Parco
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

till this point i get no error and data goes at their location, as i check with select, than i try to execute:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mypath\\Affiliazione.csv'
    INTO TABLE Affiliazione
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ();
```

and i got this error:

> `0 row(s) affected, 10 warning(s):`
>   `1452 Cannot add or update a child row:`
>   `a foreign key constraint fails (parchidb.affiliazione, CONSTRAINT`
>   `affiliazione_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (Parco) REFERENCES Parco`
>   `(Nome) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

repeated for 10 times and

> `Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 10  Warnings: 10`

Here are the csv that i'm trying to use to automatically populate my database:

Agenzia.csv:

```
10000000001;primaA;pass1;via del test, 1;818811111
10000000002;secondaA;pass2;via del test, 2;818811112
10000000003;terzaA;pass3;via del test, 3;818811113
10000000004;quartaA;pass4;via del test, 4;818811114
10000000005;quintaA;pass5;via del test, 5;818811115
10000000006;sestaA;pass6;via del test, 6;818811116
10000000007;settimaA;pass7;via del test, 7;818811117
10000000008;ottavaA;pass8;via del test, 8;818811118
10000000009;nonaA;pass9;via del test, 9;818811119
10000000010;decimaA;pass10;via del test, 10;818811110
```

Parco.csv:

```
primoP;Via Loreto, 66;3406288992;63041
secondoP;Piazza Trieste e Trento, 1;3932265113;12060
terzoP;Via Cavour, 24;3915863173;81024
quartoP;Via Duomo, 95;3555935297;57019
quintoP;Via Sergente Maggiore, 142;3376561224;56010
sestoP;Piazza della Repubblica, 46;3889300484;88070
settimoP;Via San Pietro Ad Aram, 135;3369112023;20080
ottavoP;Via Belviglieri, 117;3131026198;191
nonoP;Via Tasso, 97;3318941971;6025
decimoP;Via Nizza, 22;3202997859;31010
```

Affiliazione.csv:

```
10000000001;primoP
10000000002;secondoP
10000000003;terzoP
10000000004;quartoP
10000000005;quintoP
10000000006;sestoP
10000000007;settimoP
10000000008;ottavoP
10000000009;nonoP
10000000010;decimoP
```

Strange things is that if try to insert manually 'Affilizione''s values i got no references error, is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: oh sorry i deleted before posting, updated

Comment: My guess is that there are some invisible characters in Affiliazione.csv file, probably at the end of each line. Perhaps the lines are terminated by `\r\n` and not by just `\n`. In this case the names will not match, even though the names look like the same to the naked eye.

Comment: i thought that too, bacause i've done that with excel so i manually rewrited all the files using block note!

Comment: \r\n works in windows 10.

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: thanks to notepad plus plus i understand that even simple text editor use '\r\n' instead of '\n' so i'll try to replace the load instruction to all and update the post if it gets resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. that wai it '\r\n' instead of '\n'. Discovered with notepad++. To make it work just replace `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` with `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`